# Dynamically Sizing the height of ListView components

Tags: android, listview

for practice I am writing an activity that takes a string from a local DB and puts it into a listView.  However the string's are of different length, ranging from a couple of characters, to a couple of sentences.  Write now I can take them and place them in a listView but, not all of the strings fit.  I was curious if/how you can dynamically choose the height of each part of the list view so that the entire string can fit in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your list item layout is using `wrap_content` for its `layout_height` attribute. If you're using a fixed height, it won't scale to fit larger strings. If you want the lists a specific size except for in situations as mentioned, you can also add a `android:minHeight` attribute as well with the dimension you want as standard.

Also, make sure your `TextView` is set to multiline (attribute `android:singleLine="false"`).

Comment: I currently have wrap_content, but the text just continues off the screen, so each part is only one line, is there a different solution?

Comment: You should probably edit in your XML for the list item, but it could be that your TextView is set to singleLine. Try adding `android:singleLine="false"`. Also, if your TextView is set to `wrap_content` for the width as well, that might be your problem. If that's the case, then your options vary depending on whether you're using a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, or something else.

Comment: the `android:singleLine="false"` was the problem, thank you very much!